# Language of Files

Tags: command-line, bash, files

As you can write in different languages in Linux, what language is used for all or many of the files that are on Linux from the very installation? An example is the`/root/.bashrc` file, what language is that file written in?

Comment: You mean programming language?

Comment: @Zanna yes, that is what I meant by language.

Comment: Many of the configuration files and utilities on Ubuntu are shell scripts as mentioned in an answer. You'll also find many scripts written in python and perl. But the Linux kernel and afaik the core-utils stuff is written in C (with some assembly language bits in the case of the kernel)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/root/.bashrc` is a [shell script](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_script).  Basically, it can contain any command that you could type at the command prompt.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Ya, that answered part of my question. Thanks.